# How do I export aws lambda logs(Prints) to Kinesis Data Streams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

[image]I have been Stocked on how to send Lambda logs(Prints) directly to Amazon Kinesis Data Stream. I have Found the way to send Logs from Cloud watch but I would like to send every single prints to kinesis data streams. I have a doubt if I send data from cloud watch does it stream real time prints records to kinesis or not? On this case I would like to use lambda as producer and through the kinesis data S3 as a consumer .

below I have attached a flow work of my conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check the lambda extensions, which helps into direct ingestion of the logs to custom destinations. Its helpful incase you want to avoid cloudwatch costs

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-extensions-to-send-logs-to-custom-destinations/

Comment: do you know why this error occurs when I clicked in start streaming on  cloudwatch log subscription`s start streaming button  . "
Could not deliver test message to specified Firehose stream. Check if the given Firehose stream is in ACTIVE state."

Comment: Most probably would be an IAM issue permission. check if the IAM role has trust policy enabled for logs.amazonaws.com so that cloudwatch can assume the role. This is the same role which you have passed to the subscription filter. another one is if the IAM role has permissions to send data to the Firehose.

Comment: This is the first time I have been trying to set permission so not idea of it . I  think i am stocked in creating permission from cloud watch log to firehose . how do i check logs.amazonaws.com and where should i check this ?

Comment: This is not the actually problem because i already tried giving admistrator access to the role

Comment: The issue is not permissions of that role, you need to allow logs.amazonaws.com  to assume that role.   Check the trust policy part if that is setup correctly. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#DestinationKinesisExample

Answer (score 0):

You have to create [CouldWatch Subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html) for the Lambda's log stream you want to save to S3. So you would do:

```
CW Logs subscription ---> Firehose ---> S3
```

Comment: Thank you for this. but I would like to know if I subscription to cw logs than how the record send to firehose . I mean when lambda had multiple prints then does it send records of each print one by one to firehose or not ?

Comment: @rabinadhikari Just try and see. Its not difficult to setup. You can also subscribe lambda to CW Logs (or lambda in firehose), and do some pre-processing of the records, before you save them to S3.

Comment: so you mean we can send each print records with pre-processing to kinesis one by one through cwv logs ?

Comment: @rabinadhikari I think they are going bulks, not sure. Just run it and check. This is the only way to get data from CW Logs, unless you will develop fully custom solution yourself.

Comment: ok I got it. I will try this one and see what will happen